# Просуммировать все значения в списке списков

Tags: python

```
Scores=[['4840'], ['3496', '2376'], ['1594'], ['871', '1869'], ['8915', '2398', '5663'], ['691', '9144'], ['7865'], ['6322', '9130', '1362'], ['1562'], ['2161', '1331'], ['8033', '8118', '2342'], ['1042', '1717'], ['5177', '6470'], ['5299'], ['4623', '6579', '8083'], ['7531', '1097'], ['6483', '6167', '6027'], ['3929', '3845', '7326'], ['8088', '5322'], ['5667', '7433', '8428'], ['1364'], ['2989', '4879'], ['4713', '2923'], ['8123', '7604', '153'], ['8285', '627', '2317'], ['9380', '3851'], ['6351', '8575'], ['4'], ['736'], ['979', '9346'], ['8778', '3565', '9234'], ['8939'], ['4358'], ['413', '5751', '4369'], ['1700', '9680', '5889'], ['159', '1946'], ['7488', '3845', '3445'], ['5172', '7039', '3127'], ['4', '3'], ['42']]

print([sum(i[2:6]) for i in Scores])
```

Comment: `i[2:6]` зачем нужен этот кусок кода?

Comment: Не знаю , мне просто нужно все это суммировать и выявить ответ , я просто не понимаю где тут ошибка

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `sum(map(int, chain.from_iterable(scores)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

способ 1:

```
print(sum(sum(int(i) for i in obj) for obj in Scores))
```

способ 2:

```
print(sum(sum(map(int, obj)) for obj in Scores))
```

способ 3:

```
print(sum(map(lambda obj: sum(map(int, obj)), Scores)))
```

способ 4: изврат и экзотика :)

```
print(eval(str(Scores).replace(',', '').replace('\'', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(' ', '+')))
```

способ 5: тот же изврат, но покороче :)

```
import re

print(eval(re.sub('[,\'\[\]]', '', str(Scores)).replace(' ', '+')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Если надо найти сумму чисел в каждом списку то так;

```
print([sum(int(el) for el in i) for i in Scores])
```

а если надо найти сумму всех значение, то так;

```
print(sum(int(el) for i in Scores for el in i))
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

сумма всех значений:

```
Scores = [['4840'], ['3496', '2376'], ['1594'], ['871', '1869'], ['8915', '2398', '5663'], ['691', '9144'], ['7865'],
          ['6322', '9130', '1362'], ['1562'], ['2161', '1331'], ['8033', '8118', '2342'], ['1042', '1717'],
          ['5177', '6470'], ['5299'], ['4623', '6579', '8083'], ['7531', '1097'], ['6483', '6167', '6027'],
          ['3929', '3845', '7326'], ['8088', '5322'], ['5667', '7433', '8428'], ['1364'], ['2989', '4879'],
          ['4713', '2923'], ['8123', '7604', '153'], ['8285', '627', '2317'], ['9380', '3851'], ['6351', '8575'], ['4'],
          ['736'], ['979', '9346'], ['8778', '3565', '9234'], ['8939'], ['4358'], ['413', '5751', '4369'],
          ['1700', '9680', '5889'], ['159', '1946'], ['7488', '3845', '3445'], ['5172', '7039', '3127'], ['4', '3'],
          ['42']]

general_sum = sum(sum(map(int, values)) for values in Scores)
print(general_sum)
```